# Replace this or that with this

Tags: jquery, replace

So, let's say you want to replace a part of a href of some `a's`:

```
$("a").each(function() {
    var link = $(this).attr("href").replace("this", "that");
    $(this).attr("href", link);
});
```

But how would you go about replacing multiple parts of the string with the same? Let's say you want to replace all occurence of `this` and `that` with `what`.

How can you do this most efficiently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
 var link = $(this).attr("href").replace(/(this|that)/g, 'what');
```

Example of result

```
var str = "test this and that with what"
str.replace(/(this|that)/g, 'what'); //result "test what and what with what"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression to replace all occurances.

```
var link = $(this).attr("href").replace(/this/g, "that");
```

Answer (score 0):

don't know about the efficiency of that technique.. but you can always do:

```
var link = $(this).attr("href").replace("this", "what").replace("that", "what");
```